# Where can I obtain Ubuntu Software and Server CDs and a manual

Tags: canonical

I live in nigeria and I need to obtain the CDs + a manual for the desktop and server versions of Ubuntu 11.10.

Is there any information available where i can order these?

Answer (score 3):

Alas, Ubuntu no longer distribute free CDs, see :

http://www.ubuntu.com/shipit

However, you may find some assistance with physical media from someone in the Ubuntu Nigeria community

http://www.nairaland.com/11508/ubuntu-linux/72

I don't believe there has ever been "official" printed manuals for Ubuntu, aside from commercially produced books, but learning to use the `man` and `info` utilities will be useful, as will the community documentation available at

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/